# Spring Security 4: Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-security

The issue is that I'm getting `Request method 'POST' not supported` error on tomcat when I click on login button.

Here is my code :

```
<form class="omb_loginForm" action="${/login}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">Invalid username and password.</div>
                            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">You have been logged out.</div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="ssoId"
                                    placeholder="email address" autocomplete="off" required="required"
                                    style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" />
                            </div>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                                    placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required="required"
                                    style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" />
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
                        </form>
```

My Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        System.out.println("login page");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }
```

And my spring security config:

```
package com.mintad.spring.security;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("USER");
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("root123").roles("ADMIN");
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("root123").roles("ADMIN","DBA");
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from userroles where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                // .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                // .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and
                // hasRole('DBA')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome").usernameParameter("ssoId")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }
}
```

I've tried removing method type from controller but in vain. Please, any help is welcomed !

Comment: Do you have a Contoller method annotated with `RequestMethod.POST`?

Comment: @bphilipnyc : no I don't. But I don't understand why it works for another example I downloaded but not mine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a shame :(

The solution is to use @ instead of $  and add extension th to action as follows :

```
<form class="omb_loginForm" th:action="@{/login}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Now I have another issue is that defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome") is not working... Welcome page is in the same level as index page under templates folder. I have the error 404 when opening this url <websiteurl>/welcome. I'm using thymleaf and I'm beginner. My tiles definitions file is in my answer